# Probar si un document.getElement es un numero

Tags: javascript, html

soy muy nuevo en javascript y quería saber si hay una manera de saber si un `document.getElementsByTagName('input')` es un numero o no para validar el dato que entra en el nuevo input creado a través de `crearinput()`. Intente con `typeof` pero solo me regresa false. No tiene porque ser necesariamente un `document.getElementsByTagName` pero no sabia como encontrar los nuevos inputs creados en el form

```
    <button id="btn">boton</button>
    <form id="formulario">
        <input placeholder="dsad" required>
    </form>
    <button id="btn2">Boton</button>
    <script src="js.js"></script>
```

```
const formulario = document.getElementById("formulario");
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
const btn2 = document.getElementById("btn2");

btn.addEventListener("click", e => {
    crearinput()
})

function crearinput() {
    const formulario = document.getElementById("formulario");
    var btn = document.createElement('input');
    formulario.appendChild(btn)
}
btn2.addEventListener("click", e => {
    numero = document.getElementsByTagName('input').value;
    if (typeof numero == 'numer') {
        alert("numero")
    }
    else {
        alert("nah")
    }
})
})
```

Comment: Quieres crear `input`s dinámicos (0 a n) y en otro botón validar si lo que ingreso el usuario en cualesquiera de esos inputs generados es un valor númerico, es eso lo que se busca?

Comment: @Rigoberto Ramirez Cruz Si, eso es lo que se busca

Comment: Deberia el usuario poder ingreso otro dato que no sea de tipo númerico?

Comment: @Rigoberto Ramirez nop, la idea es que el usuario solo ingrese números y verificar que estos sean números pero cuando creo el nuevo input no sé como identificarlo y trabajar con ellos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes agregarle un distintivo a los inputs generados al momento de crearlos para facilitar acceder a ellos posteriormente. En este ejemplo, se agrega una clase, puede ser un atributo o alguna forma de identificarlos por ID posteriormente.

Y en el método que hace la validación se busca a todos los elementos que tengan el identificador antes mencionado y se evalúa si el valor que ingresó el usuario es numérico, en este caso estoy usando [isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) pero puede ser cualquier otra forma que sea más ad hoc a lo que se busca.

```js
const formulario = document.getElementById("formulario");
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
const btn2 = document.getElementById("btn2");

btn.addEventListener("click", e => {
    crearinput()
})

function crearinput() {
    const formulario = document.getElementById("formulario");
    const btn = document.createElement('input');
    // agrego clase que servirá para identificar el elemento a posteriori
    btn.classList.add('validate-is-number')
    formulario.appendChild(btn)
}

btn2.addEventListener("click", e => {
    const toValidate = document.querySelectorAll('input.validate-is-number')
   

    // Validar cada uno de los elementos
    for (const element of toValidate) {
      var val = element.value
      
      if (isNum(val)) {
        console.log('Es numero')
      }
    }
})

function isNum(value) {
  // Verificar con Regex o alguna otra forma
  return !isNaN(value)
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">boton</button>
  <form id="formulario">
      <input placeholder="dsad" required>
  </form>
  <button id="btn2">Boton</button>
```

Otra opción sería forzar el input que sea de tipo numérico:

```js
  function crearInput() {
    ...
    const btn = document.createElement('input')
    btn.setAttribute('type', 'number');
    ... 
  }
```

PS no se porque la variable que almacena el input se llama btn, eso es un poco confuso, procura nombrar las variables/funciones/etc tal que se entienda el propósito de ser y no sea engañoso.